# Converting to For loop javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop

I have the following js code:

```
    function splitter(somestr){
     "use strict";
     var bb0 = somestr.split(":");
     return bb0;
}

    var plist = [t_str, f_str, c_str, d_str, e_srt, o_str, k_str];

    var aa0 = splitter(plist[0]);
    var aa1 = splitter(plist[1]);
    var aa2 = splitter(plist[2]);
    var aa3 = splitter(plist[3]);
    var aa4 = splitter(plist[4]);
    var aa5 = splitter(plist[5]);
    var aa6 = splitter(plist[6]);
```

I wanted to convert this into a for loop:

```
    for (var k = 0; k < plist.length; k++) {
    var a = plist[k];
    var aa[k] = splitter(a);
    return aa[k];}
```

What am i doing wrong, am I calling the splitter function within the loop incorrectly?

Comment: Without knowing what is inside the array, the expected output vs what you get, we can't answer this.

Comment: `aa[0]` is not the same as `aa0`

Comment: You are calling the function correctly, but you cannot have a variables declaration like `var aa[k]`. Instead of having variables with numeric indexes, use an array instead. So, before the loop: `var aa = [];` and in the loop `aa[k] = ...;`.

Comment: each element n the array plist is in the form 8:20 i.e. a time. The splitter function splits the desired element in p-list into a 2-wide array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to perform the `splitter` operation on each element of the `plist` array and store the results somewhere. Try:

```
var aa = plist.map(function(element){return splitter(element);})
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to store the values in `aa`, meaning you need to move it up in scope:

```
var aa = [];
for (var k = 0; k < plist.length; k++) {
    var a = plist[k];
    aa[k] = splitter(a);
}

// Do something with aa
```

Answer (score -1):

Following doesn't make sense

```
function splitter(somestr){
 **"use strict"; // This is not making sense**
 var bb0 = somestr.split(":");
 return bb0;
```

}

and also in the following `a` must be the an array to whom you are going to assigning values.

```
for (var k = 0; k < plist.length; k++) {
    var a = plist[k];
    var aa[k] = splitter(a);
    return aa[k];}
```

Comment: Are you saying strict mode is not a good idea or do you not know what strict mode is?

Comment: @user2951753 What??? Please read about [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode). Also why in world `a` should be an array?  `a` is passed to `splitter()`, and treated as a string there...

Comment: I've commented strict mode out.